# How to identify android and linux user with userAgent

Tags: javascript, android, linux

At my desktop website i got this code to redirect mobile users to the mobile version of my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))
{
   location.replace("http://YOUR-MOBILE-SITE.com");
}
-->
</script>
```

And that works on iOS but then i want something like

```
else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))
{
    location.replace...
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/blackberry/i))
{
    location...
}
```

What should be instead of /android/ and /blackberry/?

And how to do it with linux? /linux/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexof("Android")!=-1)
    {
        location.replace...
    }
    //User Agent in BlackBerry 6 and BlackBerry 7/BlackBerry Device Software 4.2 to 5.0
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexof("BlackBerry") ! = -1)
    {
        location...
    }
    //User Agent in BlackBerry Tablet OS
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexof("PlayBook") ! = -1)
    {
        location...
    }
    //User Agent in BlackBerry 10
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexof("BB10") ! = -1)
    {
        location...
    }
else if (navigator.userAgent.indexof("linux") ! = -1)
    {
        location...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to target specific width but not devices.
You have televsions, tabletes, smartphone, semismartphones with different resolutions and screen sizes running android. Also You can run any number of browsers on Android like firefox.

```
@media (max-width:320px){
///codezz
}
@media (max-width:1024px){
///codezz
}
```

etc'

IF you insist on doing it with user agents see this link for the signature:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > 0){
    //    runcodez
   };
```